# Material Shader for different color rings/areas for a plant trunk (Equisetopsida)

Tags: materials, shaders, color, shader-nodes

i want to recreate the trunk of this plant with shaders, but I don't have that much experience how i could do this. Could someone show me a node setup to emulate the trunk? I would be really happy! So it's more or less about how I can make the different color rings and the transitions, which aren´t quite perfect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using a Wave texture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a *Gradient Texture*, isolated on the Z-axis, as well as scaled with a *Mapping Node* and repeated using a *Fraction (Math) Node*. This way, the "taper" starts at the bottom of each "segment" and can be used as the basis for a *Bump* as well as a *ColorRamp*:

[image: Bamboo]

However, for added realism, I would suggest warping the input vectors with a *Noise Texture* first, which will both distort the "seams", as well add some "organic" bumpiness to the surface:

[image: Distort]

Here's a setup that better replicates your sample image - I added a bit of "plant subsurface" (low value) and changed the subsurface radius values to slightly favor green (0.2,0.6,0.4). Notice the pattern is different on all of the "sticks - this is because I duplicated them in *Edit Mode*) - if you duplicate them in *Object Mode* , the pattern will be identical because the texture is using *Object Texture Co-ordinates* which are relative to the object's origin - A workaround is to use *Generated Texture-Coordinates*, but that will require some slight alterations to the *Mapping Node* (to avoid distortion):

[image: BetterView]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That is really awesome! Unfortunately i can´t really reproduce it, altough i made the same settings. I played around with the Divide Node etc. but regardless what i´m doing, rings like yours don't come out so clear and the white edge isn't visible either. I am attaching a screenshot of my node setup in my question. Thank you again!

Comment: Some of the way the values apply are dependent on the size of the base mesh as object texture coordinates place the 0,0,0, mark directly at the origin (usually the center) of an object and increment (+ or )- from there (depending on direction) - Notice I scaled by 4 on the Z of my Mapping node - you may need to change your scale value  differently (higher or lower) to make it "fit" your object.

Comment: Yes i found that also out but i have to increase the Mix Node after the Noise Texture to something like 0.95 so that the rings arent distorted to much like in your example. And then the noise is almost gone. I attached the picture it in the question.

Comment: Try reducing the scale of your noise texture.

Comment: Aah this was the problem the whole time. Thank you again, it´s awesome! :))